# Numpy V^t T V - looking for faster way to compute

Tags: performance, numpy, matrix, orthogonal

Anyone have thoughts on a fast way for numpy speed up `V^t T V` for orthogonal `V` and tridiagonal symmetric `T`?

Comment: Speed up relative to what? Have you tried anything that turned out too slow?

Comment: Have you tried the straight forward `np.dot(V.T, np.dot(T,V))` or `V.T@T@V`?  Or you hoping that the special geometry of `V` and `T` can be used to calculate it faster?

Comment: Hi, this is what I have tried for i in range(N):
  for j in range(N):
    for k in range(N):
      tv[k] = offDiag[k-1]*v[j, k-1] + Diag[k]*v[j, k] + OffDiag[k]*v[j, k+1]
Q[i,j] = np.dot(v[i,:], tv)

Comment: For multiplication by diagonal on 100x100 matrix a thousand times, I get 13.58 seconds for np.dot(np.diag(D),A), 1.72 seconds for (D*A.T).T and 1.69 seconds for D[:,newaxis]*A